# Branches of log

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I don't really understand what branches of log are in complex analysis. The definition I have is that 'a branch of log $z$ in G is a continuous function $l$ in G such that, for each $z$ in G, the value $l(z)$ is a logarithm of z.

---

I know this definition, but somehow still have a hard time understanding the concept. I may be overthinking it... I thought a branch of log z was essentially an identical log of z, just rotated around the plane by a constant times 2π. So just the same log z, but on top or underneath the original one (if you graphed it using $\theta$ as the z axis). Is this correct? Does this mean that there is only one branch in each [0,2π] interval? (or is this interval open?)

Comment: What don't you understand from the Wikipedia page on this subject?

Comment: It is equivalent to defining the polar coordinate $\theta$ in $z = r\exp(i\theta)$. The most general definition involves an arbitrary non-self intersecting oriented curve that starts at the origin and moves away to infinity that defines the branch cut across which $\theta$ will jump by $2\pi$.

Comment: Do you understand $\arcsin$ or $\arccos$?

Comment: The common branches are for $t \in (a,a+1), r \in (0,\infty), L_a(r e^{2i\pi t}) = r+2i\pi t$. But there are many more : for $t \in (0,\infty)$ and $r \in (2^t,2^{t+1})$ let $\ell(r e^{2i \pi t}) = r+2i\pi t$, this is a weird branch of $\log$ whose domain of analyticity and continuity is a spiral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seek an inverse $f(z)$ to the exponential function.  So we need $f \circ \exp(z)=z$.  Since $\exp{z}= \exp{(z+2i\pi)}$ this identity cannot be simultaneously satisfied by $z$ and $z'$ if $z-z'$ is a multiple of $2\pi i$.  Hence we have to assume that the domain contains only one representative of each equivalence class $z+2i\pi \mathbb{Z}$.